# How to bind dynamically created form fields to an object in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Angular 2 I'm trying to build a generic form for an arbitrary object by dynamically creating input fields for each attribute.

Given an object `entity` I loop through each attribute, using a pipe to get the array of attributes.

A field is created for each attribute `key` which I then want to bind back to the `entity`.

Here is the code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let key of entity | keys">
  <td><label for="{{key.key}}">{{key.key}}</label></td>
  <td><input id="{{key.key}}" type="text" [(ngModel)]="key.value"></td>
</tr>
```

So the problem is that the fields are bound using `[(ngModel)]="key.value"` to the `keys` rather than to `entity`.

Is there any way to bind the field to the `entity` instead?

Or is there another way to update the values on the entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `index` in `ngFor` to bind the entity value.

```
<tr *ngFor="let key of entity | keys;let i = index">
  <td><label for="{{key.key}}">{{key.key}}</label></td>
  <td><input id="{{key.key}}" type="text" [(ngModel)]="entity[i].value"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman , this answer did not quite work but it got me started. The solution that works for me is to bind to `[(ngModel)]="entity[key.key]"`